# Android Bluetooth Connectivity with RN42 Module

Tags: android, bluetooth, embedded

I'm trying to connect my app to the RN42 module.

```
            // Create a socket based on the application ID with a paired device
            // Fetch the published UUIDs from the mbed and use the first one
            bluetoothSocket = connectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(connectedDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());

            // Connect to the device
            if (!bluetoothSocket.isConnected())
                bluetoothSocket.connect();

            // Create the input and output streams for sending/receiving messages
            socketInput = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            socketOutput = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
```

I've got these in the Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

I'm getting this error when I call `bluetoothSocket.connect()`.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect()' on a null object reference
```

After calling this line

```
bluetoothSocket = connectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(connectedDevice.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
```

I've inspected the variable `bluetoothSocket` using Android Studio and it's not null. It somehow becomes null when `bluetoothSocket.connect()` is called.

Is that the expected behaviour? What can I do to fix it? The RN42 module works fine as I've tested it with the RN Bluetooth Chat app on Play Store.

I'm on Android 5.1 on a Nexus 7 if that helps.

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem. So please can you provide me detai. what happened to your problem? and that problem is resolved? Please provide me sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to sort the issue by removing my Bluetooth connectivity code and instead basing it around the `Android Bluetooth Chat` example. I don't know what the exact issue was but Bluetooth Chat example managed to fix it. Nothing obvious stands out so my best guess is, it was something subtle. If you are having a similar issue and connection between RN42 and Android is fiddly, create a sample Bluetooth Chat application and reuse that Bluetooth connectivity code.

Many less headaches! :)

Comment: Sorry this is late; but did everything just "work out of the box" for you? I was literally attempting the same exact thing with Bluetooth Chat but it's failing for me. I can pair but not make the connection.

Comment: Hey, yes it has worked out of the box for me. Have you tried it with the RN Bluetooth Chat from Play Store to make sure your module is working correctly?

Comment: I just downloaded that app, so I'll try it out when I get home. It should work, I have used this RN42 with "closed source" Android apps and it works. So I'll have to keep poking around.

Comment: I am also facing the similar problem. I paired device from Bluetooth-settings but now I am trying to send a command to the device but I didn't get the response from the device. Application hangs in read stream. So please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

[Seethis reference guide for the module](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/bluetooth_cr_UG-v1.0r.pdf) (p. 21) .

This might or might not apply to your case but is probably worth trying. They have special recommendations (default UUID and custom UUID respectively) for the module when connecting to Android devices.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help, I'm using the UUID which the device returns anyway so that rules the UUID issue out. Any other ideas?

Comment: @mfro This is what worked for me. I finally got the RN42 device connected to my Android Bluetooth Chat. I had to change the UUIDs in "BluetoothChatService.java" to be 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB like it says in the document you linked. I also had to set the remote bluetooth address on the RN42 to the android and initiate connection via RN42. Thanks! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Use the createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord instead. Insecure socket allows the RFCOMM to communicate with a non-authenticated paired device. Embedded devices like the RN42 or KC2114 have a difficult time performing authenticated pairing, because user interaction is required (numeric comparison, yes-no response). The "Just Works" automatic pairing will not produce an authenticated pairing. KC2114 supports both automatic authenticated pairing (with a small hack) and Just Works non-authenticated pairing.